# Array Of JS Dates How To Group By Days

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, momentjs

I'm trying to figure out the most optimal and with as minimum amount of loops way to group my array of js dates objects from this: (Take a note this is browser console output it's actully real JS dates like new Date())

```
[Sat Aug 08 2015 08:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Sat Aug 08 2015 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Sun Aug 09 2015 08:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Sun Aug 09 2015 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Mon Aug 10 2015 18:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Mon Aug 10 2015 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Tue Aug 11 2015 18:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Tue Aug 11 2015 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Wed Aug 12 2015 18:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Wed Aug 12 2015 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)]
```

to oragnized array with each date of the same day inside a "chunk" so I can display it on the UI "Aug 08" and show 2 or how many dates inside that day.

for example:

```
[{day: 'Aug 08', times:[Sat Aug 08 2015 08:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time), Sat Aug 08 2015 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)]}]
```

My current way I thought about doing it was

```
var startDays = _.map(occurences, function (date) {
  return moment(date).startOf('day').format();
});
```

After that to get unique days:

```
_.uniq(startDays, true)
```

and after I got the unique days another loop to add the same day to this group as you can see by now you might see why I don't like it and this is why I would love to get some smart help because nothing gets to my head with this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at using _.groupBy instead of _.map?

Comment: @GruffBunny i wasn't aware of it! I will look into that now thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Underscore has the [**_.groupBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function which should do exactly what you want:

```
var groups = _.groupBy(occurences, function (date) {
  return moment(date).startOf('day').format();
});
```

This will return an object where each key is a day and the value an array containing all the occurrences for that day.

To transform the object into an array of the same form as in the question you could use map:

```
var result = _.map(groups, function(group, day){
    return {
        day: day,
        times: group
    }
});
```

To group, map and sort you could do something like:

```
var occurrenceDay = function(occurrence){
    return moment(occurrence).startOf('day').format();
};

var groupToDay = function(group, day){
    return {
        day: day,
        times: group
    }
};

var result = _.chain(occurences)
    .groupBy(occurrenceDay)
    .map(groupToDay)
    .sortBy('day')
    .value();
```

Comment: is there a way to get back an array? The order is important and I don't really need reference for each group so if it's an array is fine. Trying to iterate over it and {{#each object}} is not supported with meteor

Comment: thanks! Is the order guaranteed to be the same? hopefully groupby can' mess it up I thought it might because It's an object so maybe a more safer bet is not even convert it to object and have some custom function to do it right to array?

Comment: The order of keys in a javascript object can't be guaranteed so to be certain you could use _.sorttBy after the mapping. I've added an extra snippet that shows all that being done using underscore's chaining.

Comment: It works great thanks a lot for your help! out of curiosity is there a way to test how fast is this? I always have in my mind a limitation or a fear to use too many loops so I think i might give it a test and see how it works :)

Comment: There's [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) for trying out js performance. If performance is an issue then a well written pure js solution would generally be quicker. But what you gain in performance you usually lose out in code clarity and expressiveness.

Comment: I would suggest to remove `moment` due to the package size it comes with. You can JS `Date`.

Answer (score 16):

Presuming your data is actually strings, I don't know why you think you need either of those libraries. You are just grouping strings based on substrings.

ES5 introduced [*reduce*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce), which is great for accumulating things:

A helper to create an array of dates:

```
// Generate a dates array given a start date and how many to create:
function genDates(startDate, count) {
  var d = new Date(+startDate),
      dates = [d];
  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
    d = new Date(+d);
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 10);
    dates.push(d);
  }
  return dates;
}
```

This answer originally dealt with strings, modified to work with Dates:

```
// Generate date key 'MMM dd'
// Replaces use of moment.js
function getDateKey(date) {
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  return m[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + ((d<10?'0':'') + d);
}

// Generate an array in format [{day:'MMM dd', times:[d0, d1, ...]}, ...]
// Replaces use of underscore.js
var obj = dates.reduce(function(acc, d) {
            var p = getDateKey(d)
            if (!acc[0].hasOwnProperty(p)) acc[0][p] = [];
            acc[0][p].push(d);
            return acc;
          },[{}])
          .reduce(function(acc, v){
            Object.keys(v).forEach(function(k){acc.push({day:k, times:v[k]})});
            return acc;
          },[]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

If optimal performance is the key, the above is [*20 times faster*](http://jsperf.com/libraries-vs-pojs) than the underscore + Moment solution for an array of 5 to 100 dates. To make it faster, remove all use of iterators and libraries and use a single function with for loops. Note that the above is only one line of code longer than the solution using Moment.js and underscore.js.

Comment: it's not string it's actually date objects it's just the console output so it's possible to use inside moment(date) or simple built in JS date object it's same as new date(). But thank you for the way! It seems interesting I will try to adopt this technique to my loop with momet() checks. P.S both libraries are available in my project so using them just makes life easier hopefully underscore reduce is the same?

Comment: digging deeper into this I definitely learned a technique to add and check an array I could definitively implement something like this to work. But underscore actually has _.groupBy makes life easier. So just wanted to thank you for the time, I learned from this and in the future I will be able to think about the solution right away in my head!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to grouping also by **year** or (and) **month** with day - I recommend to use my solution.

*In answers above if you'll get different month or year with the same day - your grouping will be incorrect.*

Look at the **good solution**:

```
_.groupBy(arrayOfDates, function (el) {
      return (el.getFullYear() + '|y|') + (el.getMonth() + '|m|') + (el.getDate() + '|d|');
    });
```

What I do here? Just create an unique keys for each date, which includes: year, month and day. And then I group an array by this unique key.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA4s2.png)

Answer (score 0):

### ES2024

You can now use the built-in [`Object.groupBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) or [`Map.groupBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/groupBy):

```js
const randomHour = () => Math.floor(23 * Math.random());

const occurrences = [
  new Date(2024, 0, 1, randomHour()),
  new Date(2024, 0, 2, randomHour()),
  new Date(2024, 0, 1, randomHour()),
  new Date(2024, 2, 1, randomHour()),
];

const result = Object.groupBy(
  occurrences,
  (date) => `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

> [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_groupby) is ok (~ 82% as of 2024-02-15) but not great yet.

Obviously if you don't want to group by the year, you just leave that part out of the unique key you create.

Answer (score -6):

Why do need this optimization? If your array is not large enoguh than you probably don't need to optimize your algorithm.

I am not familiar with the given js libraries, but you can group your array by days with one loop. But you need to somehow determine the current day in the array and then create corresponding js object with a day-field and a times-array field and then add this object to your resulting array.
It will be much faster if you presort your array before implementing this algorithm.