# AngularJS GroupBy Week, Month, Year and Sum

Tags: angularjs

```js
angular.module('myApp', ["angular.filter"])

.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http){
$scope.ctrl = {};

$http({
      url: 'https://ima.baguscloud.com/voezie/rest-api.php?json=expense',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json', 
      data: '',         
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.ctrl_expenses = data;
    });
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.17/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl" ng-init="var_expenses={}">
  <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl_expenses" ng-init="var_expenses[$index]=item_expense">{{ item.date|date:'Week ww of yyyy'}} Rp.{{ item.nominal_expense|number:0}},-
  </div>
</div>
</div >
```

I need to sum list of data contains "date" and "nominal_expense", but don't know how to group it by Week, Month, Year. I have tried to use GroupBy "angular.filter" to group date, but it doesn't work for week, month and year

Please help me how to make it work

I create Code Snippet that display list of date, Please help me to make them list of weeks group and list of months group

Comment: ok Achmad, there are few things to note. Using`return`, cuts your function off where you call it...there rest of the code won't be executed.  Secondly, can you show us an example of the data?

Comment: Hi @ZombieChowder I Have create Code Snippet and update the question detail

Comment: where are you showing `nominal_expense` ? I can't see it anywhere..

Comment: See Updated Code Snippet

Comment: Use lodash and momentjs

Comment: @Ash Do you have working example ?

Comment: @ZombieChowder Do you able to solve this case? I Have update the snippet

Comment: @AchmadFauzi I am not exactly sure how are trying to filter the date. It's just hat your explanation doesn't make much sense. Sorry.

Comment: @AchmadFauzi my understanding is that your question is less to do with angular and more to do with how to group data so rewrite your question

Comment: in fact its already asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890076/array-of-js-dates-how-to-group-by-days