# How to make an array of objects an object grouped by day?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

So I have an array of items, each with a date (from the moment library) and some text.

I am able to successfully turn this into an object of objects however if two or more objects have the same day, as it is mapped over it rewrites the previous item with the new one.

I must organize the object of objects based on YYYY-MM-DD format.

For example, the items array might look like this when it is console logged-

```
Array [
  Object {
    "date": 2019-08-06T19:10:00.000Z,
    "id": 0,
    "text": "Item1",
  },
  Object {
    "date": 2019-08-06T22:10:00.000Z,
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Item2",
  },
]
```

this is the code I am using to turn it into an object of objects

```
const calItemsArray = Object.assign({}, 
      ...this.props.items.map(item => 
        ({ [moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')]: [{
          text: item.text, time: moment(item.date).format('h:mm a') }] 
        }))
      );
      console.log(calItemsArray);
```

This is what would be console logged from calItemsArray based on the given data (two items with the same date)

```
Object {
  "2019-08-06": Array [
    Object {
      "text": "Item2", //item one seems to be overwritten
      "time": "6:10 pm",
    },
  ],
}
```

I would like each date to contain all of the texts and the time of items that have that date. However if one already exists, instead of adding it to the dates array of objects it just rewrites the date's object itself.

Comment: example data would help

Comment: All keys in an object must be unique, is there a reason why you need this data in an object rather than an array?

Comment: react requires for all list elements to be unique  specifying a key attribute

Comment: In that case, can you should us your code for creating the list as well?

Comment: Yes allow me a moment and ill upload more of the data, and yes I am feeding it to a calendar component that must take the data in this format in order for it to work.

Comment: I find your subject misleading.  I think it should say something like "How to group an array of objects by date".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Of JS Dates How To Group By Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890076/array-of-js-dates-how-to-group-by-days)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

Use a `reduce` function instead of `Object.assign`

```
const callItemsObject = this.props.items.reduce( ( acc, item ) => {
  let key = moment( item.date ).format( 'YYYY-MM-DD' ),
    payload = {
      text: item.text,
      time: moment( item.date ).format( 'h:mm a' )
    };

  ( acc[ key ] ) ? acc[ key ].push( payload ): ( acc[ key ] = [ payload ] );

  return acc;
}, {} );

      console.dir(calItemsObject);
```

### Example Explanation:

Now that you've provided your data model I've created some dummy data and an example. We have three dates and 5 records.

- Today: two records (items 1 and 2)
- 5 days from now: two records (items 3 and 5)
- 7 days from now: one record (item 4)

These will be pushed into an object using the date as a key in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Because there are multiple records for each day you need to store them into an Array if you are going to use the date as the key, otherwise ( *as in your attempt using `Object.assign`* ) the key's value will be overridden by the newest data.

```
{
  items: [ {
    "date": moment(),
    "id": 0,
    "text": "Item1"
  }, {
    "date": moment(),
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Item2"
  }, {
    "date": moment().add( 7, 'days' ),
    "id": 2,
    "text": "Item3"
  }, {
    "date": moment().add( 5, 'days' ),
    "id": 3,
    "text": "Item4"
  }, {
    "date": moment().add( 7, 'days' ),
    "id": 4,
    "text": "Item5"
  } ]
}
```

---

### Example:

**Note**: To your comment that says this doesn't work, by running this code ( **which isn't changed** ) I can show you that **it does**, in fact, work. If you're having issues feel free to comment, but you'll have to provide more information about your environment.

```js
let data = {items:[{"date": moment(),"id":0,"text":"Item1"},{"date": moment(),"id":1,"text":"Item2"},{"date": moment().add(7, 'days'),"id":2,"text":"Item3"}, {"date": moment().add(5, 'days'),"id":3,"text":"Item4"}, {"date": moment().add(7, 'days'),"id":4,"text":"Item5"}]};

function component(props) {
let component_proto = {};
component_proto.props = Object.assign({}, props);


component_proto.getTimes = function() {
      const callItemsObject = this.props.items.reduce( ( acc, item ) => {
      let key = moment( item.date ).format( 'YYYY-MM-DD' ),
        payload = {
          text: item.text,
          time: moment( item.date ).format( 'h:mm a' )
        };

      ( acc[ key ] ) ? acc[ key ].push( payload ): ( acc[ key ] = [ payload ] );

      return acc;
    }, {} );
   return callItemsObject;
}

return component_proto;
}


let result = component(data).getTimes();
  
  
  console.dir(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: this didn't work :(. And what is the acc suppose to be I don't really understand that part?

Comment: @goolius_boozler `acc` is short for `accumulator`. It is a reference to the second parameter of `reduce`. See more at MDN ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce )