# Is there a (near) linear way to group dates in array by day in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, complexity-theory

Is there an efficient solution to group an array of dates into objects and subarrays grouped by day?

Example:

```
groupDatesByDay([
    new Date('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
    new Date('2020-01-01 00:00:01'),
    new Date('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
    new Date('2020-01-02 00:00:01'),
    new Date('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
    new Date('2020-01-03 00:00:01'),   
])
```

The expected return value is the following, where there's an Object for each day with a key `day` representing the start of the day and an array containing all dates that are on the respective day.
I am using Date-Fns' `startOfDay()` method.

```
[
    {
        day: Date Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
        times: [
            Date Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
            Date Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:01 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
        ]
    },
    {
        day: Date Thu Jan 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
        times: [
            Date Wed Jan 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
            Date Wed Jan 02 2020 00:00:01 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
        ]
    },
    {
        day: Date Fri Jan 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
        times: [
            Date Wed Jan 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
            Date Wed Jan 03 2020 00:00:01 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
        ]
    },
]
```

I wrote a function that works, but the time complexity is really bad.
Can this be done (much) better?

```
  groupDatesByDay(dates) {
    let grouped = []

    //Push first date to grouped
    grouped.push({
      day: startOfDay(dates[0]),
      times: [dates[0]]
    })

    //Iterate dates
    dates.forEach((date, inx) => {
      if (inx == 0) {
        return
      }

      let found = false

      for (let i=0; i<grouped.length; i++) {
        //Check if grouped contains day of date already      
        if (grouped[i].day.getTime() == startOfDay(date).getTime()) {
          grouped[i].times.push(date)
          found = true
          break
        }
      }

      if (found) {
        return
      } else {
        grouped.push({
          day: startOfDay(date),
          times: [date]
        })
      }
    });
    return grouped
  }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890076/array-of-js-dates-how-to-group-by-days for options.

Comment: I am not using underscore.js which is why the linked question is irrelevant to my actual problem.

Comment: @j.Doe You were asking for "*is there a way*". The answer to that is **Yes**, using the standard group-by technique with buckets. You can implement this yourself with a `Map` or object (it's just  few lines), or you can use a utility function library

Comment: The question that @PM77-1 linked even has a non-underscore answer.

Comment: @Bergi If you say there is a way, why don't you write an answer instead of closing a perfectly relevant question **that has no answer in the question that you linked**?
The OP asked if this was possible in JavaScript, not with a third party library.
The non-underscore answer of the question that was linked is incredibly unclean as it  generates strings of every date before grouping it. This was neither asked nor is necessary for a clean solution.

Comment: @dmuensterer How is that unclean or unnecessary? The `Date` objects need to be converted to a primitive to be used as a key for grouping.

Comment: @dmuensterer Why would I write an answer when someone else already has done it? OP did not even ask for code, they asked for an approach with a better time complexity. This approach is described in the canonical topics I linked (and probably some more). Surely the OP can adapt it to use Date-Fns for generating days from his particular data.