# History sorted by day - Angular

Tags: angular, date, sorting

I am trying to create a history sorted by day just like the one in chrome :

[Chrome History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbidg.png)

However I am finding difficulty sorting all the histories by day.

This is what I have got so far :

[History Vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pin8p.png)

As you can see I can display the date of creation of the history element but I cannot order all the histories by the day of their creation.

This is what I have done so far :

I have created a json server from which I fetch and manipulate my data :

```
{
  "history": [
    {
      "id": 576791835,
      "date": "2022-06-27T18:31:38.083Z",
      
    },
    {
      "id": 911123993,
      "date": "2022-06-27T18:31:46.972Z",
    },
    {
      "id": 416865594,
      "date": "2022-06-27T18:32:54.990Z",
    },
    {
      "id": 520724162,
      "date": "2022-06-27T18:33:35.822Z",
    },
    {
      "id": 536654574,
      "date": "2022-06-27T18:33:41.821Z",
    },

  ]
}
```

I have implemented a store using NgRx, and this is my component :

```
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit{

  Contents$:Observable<History[]>;
  ContentsInOrder$:Observable<Content[]>;
  Histories$=this.facade.Histories$;
  Date= new Date;
  

  showTrash = false;

  
  onDeleteHistory(history:History){
    this.facade.deleteHistory(history);
  }

  onAddHistory(content:Data){
  
    const history : History ={
      id : Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999),
      date : new Date(),
    }
    this.store.addHistory(histo);

  @Output() click: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

  onclick(){
    this.click.emit();
  }

  openDialog(){
    this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }
}
```

This is the template of my component :

```
            <div mat-subheader *ngIf="(Histories$ | async).length===0">The documents you visit will show here</div>
  
            <mat-list-item  *ngFor="let history of Histories$ | async" class="historyClicking" (mouseover)="history.showTrash=true" (mouseout)="history.showTrash=false" (click)="onclick()">

                <div class="block">
                <div matList>{{history.id}}</div>     
        </div>
            </mat-list-item>
        
        </div> 
       
</mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is my service function:

```
  addHistory(history:History){
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL, history);
  }

  deleteHistory(id:number){
    return this.http.delete(this.apiURL+'/'+id)
  }
```

Thank you for your time !

Comment: i think you can just do it with the .sort method like data.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))

Comment: I already sorted my histories using that method in my component logic but could you show me how to do it in the template like in the history of chrome ?

Comment: try to group by day, problaby this can help u https://stackoverflow.com/a/31890611/9764641

Comment: OK I understand the logic but how do I copy the dates that are in my json file into an array ? And after that, how do I display for each day -> all the pages visited (the history)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good thing you're using observables. Looks like you've already sorted `History$` items in order. So let's add one more custom pipe to group the items by day in template. For this we loop items in one layer higher using `<ng-container>`. We create `<div>` for each day, in each we place `<mat-list-item>` - you could change this up of course but that's the basic idea of it.

Using `| datePipe` we format the date `history.date | date : 'EEEE, MMMM M, YYYY'`. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe. And then to group by day I compare them using `| slice` with the previous value (so that each day header would be rendered once).

````html
<strong *ngIf="(history.date | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY') != ((Histories$ | async)[i-1]?.date | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY')">{{ history.date | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY' }}</strong>```

I'm sure there better ways for this, like grouping the data by key/values where key is one day, but for not it works.

However if you want dates spelled e.g "Yesterday" you need to make a custom implementation for this or use some `humanizer` package. 

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="Histories$ | async">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let history of Histories$ | async; let i = index">
    <strong
      *ngIf="
        (history.date | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY') !=
        ((Histories$ | async)[i - 1]?.date | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY')
      "
    >
      <br />
      <br />
      {{ history.date | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY' }}
      <br />
    </strong>

    <br />

    <div
      *ngIf="
        (history.date | date: 'YYYY-MM-dd') ==
        (history.date | slice: 0:10).toString()
      "
    >
      <mat-list-item
        class="historyClicking"
        (mouseover)="history.showTrash = true"
        (mouseout)="history.showTrash = false"
        (click)="onclick()"
      >
        <div class="block">
          <div matList>{{ history.date }}</div>
          <div matList>{{ history.SNS }}</div>
          <div matList>{{ history.title }}</div>
          <div matList>{{ history.DMC }}</div>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
````

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-tpuwdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### Actually on second thought - the above ⬆️ looks bad.

Segregating the data with a custom pipe beforehand is better a better idea. So instead I create a custom pipe which groups items by day and then I iterate using `*ngFor` over the groups and then over the items in the group:

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'groupByDay' })
export class GroupByDayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[]): any[] {
    // this gives an object with dates as keys
    const groups = items.reduce((groups, game) => {
      const date = game.date.split('T')[0];
      if (!groups[date]) {
        groups[date] = [];
      }
      groups[date].push(game);
      return groups;
    }, {});

    // Edit: to add it in the array format instead
    const groupArrays = Object.entries(groups);

    console.log(groupArrays);
    return groupArrays;
  }
}

// [['2022-06-28', Array(1)],
// ['2022-06-27', Array(7)]]
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="Histories$ | async">
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let group of Histories$ | async | groupByDay"
  >
    <strong>{{ group[0] | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY' }}</strong>
    <br />
    <br />

    <div *ngFor="let history of group[1]">
      <mat-list-item
        class="historyClicking"
        (mouseover)="history.showTrash = true"
        (mouseout)="history.showTrash = false"
        (click)="onclick()"
      >
        <div class="block">
          <div matList>{{ history.date }}</div>
          <div matList>{{ history.SNS }}</div>
          <div matList>{{ history.title }}</div>
          <div matList>{{ history.DMC }}</div>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-p4h1vg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

---

Just some sidenotes. Usually we use `camelCase` for naming variables.

Comment: Hello Joosep, your code works for ordering the history in each day however when I try to add an element to the history by clicking on a link I get this error : ERROR Error: NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Tue Jun 28 2022 14:51:37 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)' for pipe 'SlicePipe'. The error is from this line : <div
      *ngIf="
        (history.date | date: 'YYYY-MM-dd') ===
        (history.date | slice: 0:10).toString()
      "
    >

Comment: Like I said in the code, the first solution is kind of bad - sorry. The second solution should be better.

Comment: I tried the second method and it gives me this error on the console : ERROR TypeError: game.date.split is not a function. I think it is because I am using a json file instead of an array but I am not sure

Comment: I copied your data provided. If needs be and its a json string you can use JSON.parse

Comment: Yes you were right all I needed to do was to add toString() to convert the data from the json

Comment: I just have on error and I don't know if could help me with it. When I add a history to the list, I get this error : Error: NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Wed Jun 29 2022 10:19:00 GM" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'. I don't know where it stems from so I can't fix it

Comment: `Wed Jun 29 2022 10:19:00 GM` is not an ISO string. This `2022-06-27T18:31:38.083Z` is an ISO string. Convert it to ISO string. Because as you can see `groupByDay` expects an ISO string.

Comment: Ok I understand now but where do I have to convert it in the code and how ?

Comment: Depends how to want to solve it. One way could be to check is input to `groupByDay` is a valid ISO string, if not try to convert date obj to ISO string. But I would probably find out the reason why sometimes you are passing ISO string and why other times its a Date string. Figure out the question you want to ask and make new question. That why others can also take a look at your question.